# How to assign a span title to a php variable?

Tags: php, jquery, html

Is it possible to assign a span's title to a php variable?

I have added the following span to my table which is generated from my database:

```
while ($row = $database->fetch_array($result))
{
$i=1-$i;
$class = "row".$i;


echo "<tr class='{$class}' id='{$row['productId']}'>
<td > <span  class='productId' title='{$row['productId']}' >". $row['category']."</span></td>
<td >" . $row['productNo']. "</td>
<td>" . $row['productName'].  "</td>
<td class='edit'>" . intval($row['quantity']).  "</td>
 <td>" . $row['sfLf'].  "</td>
<td>".  $row['cost']. "</td>
<td>".  $row['total']."</td>
  </tr>";
}
```

now, when i click on that span, I would like the following jQuery UI to pop up and show the data associated to the row that was clicked from another table in my database:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
//first we fade in the form when the button is clicked
var dialog = $("#editInventory").dialog({
                                            autoOpen: false,
                                            title: "Add New Order",
                                            modal: true,
                                            width: 780,
                                            show:  { effect: 'drop',direction:"up",duration:1000 },
                                            hide:  { effect: 'drop',direction:"down",duration:1000 }, 
                                            buttons: {
                                                'Submit':function() {
                                                    submitForm($("#addNewInvoice"));
                                                    },
                                                'Cancel':function() {
                                                    $(this).dialog('close');
                                                        $("#container").fadeTo('slow',1);
                                                    }
                                            }
                                         });
$(".productId").click(function() {
    dialog.dialog('open');
    $("#container").fadeTo('slow',.4);

    return false;
});
});
```

Comment: Question is not clear

Comment: Try to add your code, while adding a question

Comment: That depends on how the span is represented in your code. Also note that normally `span`s _don't_ have a title

Comment: how isn't this clear? what could I add for such general question. it is either possible or not.

Comment: How is that `span` represented, as HTML?

Comment: For parsing HTML, see `DOMDocument`

Comment: Normally the attributes of an element you want to build _are_ stored as variables.

Comment: he probably means: <span id="bla" title="<?php echo $var; ?>">something</span>

Comment: Overly broad questions are not welcome here.

Comment: Oh so you just want a yes/no answer?!  Yes then.

Comment: title is used to explain content, and can be used as tooltip.

Comment: Since your update, this looks like a jQuery question, I'm out!

Comment: ... uh-oh, and you're using a click event on a span element, I feel sorry for your users!!!

Answer (score 2):

Not directly.  Communication between HTML in a browser and PHP on a server is via HTTP with GET or POST using links or forms.

You can use JavaScript to take the title attribute from your span element and send it to the server using one of the HTTP methods.

Alternatively, since your HTML is likely being served from your PHP, you may be able to use a PHP variable to populate your SPAN title in the first place.  That all depends on how your HTML is being generated.

---

**UPDATE:**

Question is now about referring to a span element's title from a jQuery dialog.

Comment: thanks for your responses. I know how to do that, but i cannot run a query that accesses the data associated with my main table...

Comment: @theWebLover: Yep, you need to figure out what element the user clicked on, you can do that pretty easily in jQuery I'm sure, but I'm not a heavy jQuery user, because I know JavaScript ;-) - Once you figure out which jQuery function to use to figure out what element the user clicked on, you can just traverse the DOM relative to this element to access the information you need. (jQuery probably does that very well too)

Comment: awesome, I would give you a positive feedback if I had enough reputation

Answer (score 0):

This is what my brain wrote when it read your question... we can only guess.

`<span title="<?php echo $myVariable ?>" class="myClass">Span Contents Here</span>`

Comment: Indeed indeed. Updated. +1 to your answer. Much more informative.